# I am making an Inside Out thing. But only that last colors are working. Is there any solution?

Tags: python

So I'm making a scene for a school project. And I'm doing an Inside Out thing. Where each character makes Riley change her colors. But only the last color really works. The most important bit is just the if statements. This is a python code. I just need the other colors to also show. Like Blue and Red.

```
    collectorsBin = Rect(240, 0, 160, 150, opacity=50, borderWidth=5, border='black')

moodCounter = Label(0, 325, 210, size=30, fill='white')

loser = Label('LOSER!!!!', 200, 200, size=50, visible=False)

redo = Line(370, 370, 160, 370, arrowEnd=True, visible=False)

rileyArea = Rect(240, 280, 160, 120, opacity=50, borderWidth=5, border='black')

anger= Group(
            Rect(200, 220, 50, 55, fill='red'),
            Rect(200, 250, 50, 25, fill='white'),
            Rect(200, 260, 50, 15, fill='brown'),
            Polygon(225, 250, 250, 240, 250, 250, 200, 250, 200, 240, 225, 250, fill='white'),
            Line(250, 250, 200, 250, opacity=10),
            Circle(212, 232, 8, fill='white'),
            Circle(238, 232, 8, fill='white'),
            Line(225, 228, 250, 225, fill='red', lineWidth=5),
            Line(225, 228, 200, 225, fill='red', lineWidth=5),
            Line(220, 243, 230, 243, lineWidth=5, fill='white'))
            
rileyFace = Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='blanchedAlmond')
rileyEyes = Group(Circle(185, 200, 10, fill='white'),
                    Circle(215, 200, 10, fill='white'))
                    
normalHair = Group(Polygon(208, 183, 190, 186, 179, 197, 175, 227, 162, 227, 162, 185, 173, 170, 191, 165),
                    Polygon(191, 165, 199, 165, 218, 172, 230, 190, 229, 210, 225, 191, 206, 182))
                    
normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')

riley=(rileyFace, rileyEyes, normalHair)

rileyFace.centerX=315
rileyFace.centerY=350
rileyEyes.centerX=315
rileyEyes.centerY=350
normalHair.centerX=315
normalHair.centerY=350

sadness = Group(Rect(170, 210, 60, 60, fill='ivory'),
                Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='royalBlue'),
                Polygon(230, 190, 200, 180, 200, 200, 180, 220, 160, 230, 170, 180, 200, 160, 235, 187,
                fill=gradient('royalBlue', 'dodgerBlue', 'blue', start='top')),
                Circle(210, 200, 8, fill='white'),
                Line(200, 190, 220, 195, fill='royalBlue', lineWidth=8))
                
happiness = Group(Circle(200, 200, 50, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow'),
                Circle(200, 200, 50, fill='gold', opacity=50),
                Circle(223, 200, 16, fill='white'),
                 Circle(178, 200, 16, fill='white'),
                Oval(200, 228, 20, 35, fill='white', rotateAngle=70),
                Oval(197, 223, 20, 30, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow', rotateAngle=70),
                Oval(197, 223, 20, 30, fill='gold', rotateAngle=70, opacity=50),
        Polygon(156, 217, 163, 173, 192, 180, 210, 180, 200, 175, 228, 174, 250, 190, 255, 178, 252, 168, 230, 150, 200, 145,
        180, 150, 160, 152, 150, 160, 145, 185, 147, 200, fill=gradient('deepSkyBlue', 'darkBlue')),
    Rect(185, 247, 35, 75, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow'),
    Rect(185, 247, 35, 75, fill='gold'),
    Polygon(190, 247, 195, 260, 205, 260, 215, 247, 220, 247, 225, 330, 180, 330, 185, 247, fill='white'))
    
    

happiness.width/=1.5
happiness.height/=1.5

fear = Group(Polygon(200, 200, 205, 235, 215, 235, 220, 200, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Circle(200, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Circle(220, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Oval(210, 225, 25, 15, fill='white', border='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Rect(205, 235, 10, 40, fill='white'),
            Rect(205, 275, 10, 20, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Arc(221, 196, 20, 20, 300, 180, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Arc(198, 198, 20, 20, 230, 180, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Circle(210, 235, 3, fill='crimson'),
            Polygon(210, 235, 217, 228, 220, 237, fill='crimson'),
            Polygon(210, 235, 203, 240, 200, 230, fill='crimson'))
            
disgust = Group(Polygon(185, 225, 190, 243, 210, 243, 215, 225, fill='limeGreen'),
            Rect(190, 243, 20, 3, fill='lawnGreen'),
            Polygon(190, 246, 185, 265, 215, 265, 210, 246, fill='limeGreen'),
            Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='lightGreen'),
            Circle(185, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Circle(215, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Rect(175, 185, 50, 10, fill='lightGreen'),
            Polygon(200, 190, 185, 198, 175, 195, 175, 225, 163, 233, 163, 228, 170, 228, 165, 175, 193, 168, 223, 172, 233, 200, 
                    fill=gradient('lawnGreen', 'darkGreen')))
                    
disgust.centerX=36
disgust.centerY=57

happiness.centerX=39
happiness.centerY=197

fear.centerX=47
fear.centerY=327
                
sadness.centerX=120
sadness.centerY=58

anger.centerX=116
anger.centerY=189
def onMouseDrag(mouseX, mouseY):
    if(sadness.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        sadness.centerX=mouseX
        sadness.centerY=mouseY
    
    if(anger.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        anger.centerX=mouseX
        anger.centerY=mouseY
        
    if(happiness.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        happiness.centerY=mouseY
        happiness.centerX=mouseX
        
    if(fear.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        fear.centerX=mouseX
        fear.centerY=mouseY
        
    if (disgust.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        disgust.centerX=mouseX
        disgust.centerY=mouseY
        
        
        
        
def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(anger)==True):
        rileyEyes.fill='red'
        normalHair.fill='red'
        moodCounter.value=1
        
        
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(anger)==False):
        normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
        rileyEyes.fill='white'
        moodCounter.value=0
        
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(sadness)==True):
        rileyEyes.fill='blue'
        normalHair.fill='blue'
        moodCounter.value=1
        
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(sadness)==False):
        normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
        rileyEyes.fill='white'
        moodCounter.value=0
        
        
    
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(disgust)==True):
        rileyEyes.fill='green'
        normalHair.fill='lawnGreen'
        moodCounter.value=1
    
    if (collectorsBin.containsShape(disgust)==False):
        normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
        rileyEyes.fill='white'
        moodCounter.value=0
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.   You're always going to take one of the `anger` if statements, and one of the `sadness` if statements, and one of the `disgust` statement, but since they all modify the same things, only the last takes effect.

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of graphic module. Please mention what it is in your question and tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this, where we set up a default value, and only change what needs to be changed:

```
def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    eyes = 'white'
    hair = gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
    mood = 0
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(anger):
        eyes='red'
        hair='red'
        mood=1
        
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(sadness):
        eyes='blue'
        hair='blue'
        mood=1
    
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(disgust):
        eyes='green'
        hair='lawnGreen'
        mood=1
    
    rileyEyes.fill = eyes
    normalHair.fill = hair
    moodCounter.value = mood
```

If there are multiple hits, only the last one will win, but you'll need another way to solve that.